# how to pass jointMatrix to shader glTF? (java opengles20)

Tags: java, android-studio, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader, gltf

I'm trying to figure out how to display the GLTF file on Android.

I do everything according to the instructions [here.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_020_Skins.md)

it is required to pass the parameter float [] [] to the shader

I tried it this way,

```
    //joinMatrix
    float[][] jointmatrix = new float[12][];
    ...
    glUniformMatrix4fv(rs.u_jointMat, 1, false, jointmatrix, 0);
```

but the float [] [] array does not want to transmit.

```
...
attribute vec4 a_joint;
attribute vec4 a_weight;

uniform mat4 u_jointMat[12];

...
void main(void)
{
    mat4 skinMat =
        a_weight.x * u_jointMat[int(a_joint.x)] +
        a_weight.y * u_jointMat[int(a_joint.y)] +
        a_weight.z * u_jointMat[int(a_joint.z)] +
        a_weight.w * u_jointMat[int(a_joint.w)];
    vec4 pos = u_modelViewMatrix * skinMat * vec4(a_position,1.0);
    gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * pos;
}
```

please tell how to pass u_jointMat to shader glTF?

Comment: The argument to `glUniformMatrix4fv` has to be a `FloatBuffer`.  
See [Java Code Examples for org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20&method=glUniformMatrix4fv). Furthermore, the matrix has 16 fields, because it is a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Rabbid76 thanks geat site